# ionic3:error File name too lang in encode base64

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this error when I encode file to base64 when I use plugin convert to base64 in doc ionic.

error:

[image]

code angular:

```
testup()
{
for(var s of this.files)
{
  this.imgarr.push(s);
}
console.log(this.imgarr);
for(var o of this.imgarr)
{
this.base64.encodeFile(o.name).then((base64File: string) => {
alert(base64File);
this.base64array.push(base64File);

} , (err) => {
  this.presentToast(err);
  this.presentToast('error encode');
});       


}

this.http.post('url api',this.base64array, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res =>
 alert(res),
        err => {
          this.presentToast(err);
        });
```

}

string is not send to api because File name too lang  ...where is solution to send filename

Comment: Any help pleasee

Comment: I have the same isuue :( 
didn't find a solution yet...